# Calling a fragment on top of viewpager overlaps each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_bracket_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_fragment"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_bracket_activity"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:foregroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                app:tabGravity="fill"/>

            <mypackage.NonSwipeViewPager
                android:id="@+id/tabs_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The nonswipeviewpager was just a custom class where I inherited a viewpager to disable some stuff.

Anyway, I have a button on my app bar that needs to call a fragment that needs to cover the whole screen. I would call it and add a fragment on the frame layout. It worked before I added a viewpager for tab layouts. Now I'm not sure how to deal with the viewpager.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = mFM.beginTransaction();
                    mCustomFragment = CustomFragment.newInstance(mObject, mListOfObjects());
                    ft.replace(R.id.activity_fragment, mCustomFragment , "CustomFragment");
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

This is on my clicklistener of that button on the app bar.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Views are drawn in the order they are defined in your XML. If you want a View on top of another view it should appear after it or you try to use: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()